# Formatting data to API

Tags: powershell, api

I'm trying to send data trough a webcall API and have to send a specific value as number.

```
                $groupmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.SamAccountName -Recursive
                $members = ""
                foreach ($member in $groupmembers) {
                    $currentFlexAssets = (Get-ITGlueFlexibleAssets -filter_flexible_asset_type_id $Users_flex_asset_id -filter_organization_id $api__org_id -filter_name $member.name)
                    $value = $currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.'resource-url'
                    $Split = $value.split("{/}")
                    $members += $Split[7] + ", "
                }
                
                $members = $members.TrimEnd(", ")
                $members
                $members2 = 1715837278175409, 1715837265510575, 1715837270687920
```

members is the tag field build up from the string split and comma separted.

members2 is the tag field which I've typed myself for testing

memberstext are the same values but then send to a text field:

Group name
GG_Inkoop

Members
Piet van der Ven (tag)

members2
Henk de Vries (tag)
Kees Jansma (tag)
Piet van der Ven (tag)

memberstext
1715837278175409, 1715837270687920

memberstext2
1715837278175409

1715837265510575

1715837270687920

```
$api__body = @{
        type = "flexible_assets"
        attributes = @{
            organization_id = $api__org_id
            flexible_asset_type_id = $api_config.flexible_asset_type_id
            traits = @{
                $api__key_name_group_name = $groupname
                $api__key_name_members = $members
                
                $api__key_name_members2 = $members2
                $api__key_name_memberstext = $memberstext
                $api__key_name_memberstext2 = $memberstext2
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried string to integer but the value is to long

Cannot convert value "1715837270687920" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

looking at values I've seen the brackets around members2

```
traits                         {members2, memberstext, members, memberstext2...}
members2                       {1715837278175409, 1715837265510575, 1715837270687920}
memberstext                    1715837278175409, 1715837265510575, 1715837270687920
members                        1715837278175409, 1715837265510575, 1715837270687920
memberstext2                   {1715837278175409, 1715837265510575, 1715837270687920}
```

But doing $members = "{" + $members.TrimEnd(", ") + "}" results in an error from the webserver saying the value is wrong

I'm a bit stuck on this one has someone got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
                        $groupmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.SamAccountName -Recursive
                    $members = @()
                    foreach ($member in $groupmembers) {
                        $currentFlexAssets = (Get-ITGlueFlexibleAssets -filter_flexible_asset_type_id $Users_flex_asset_id -filter_organization_id $api__org_id -filter_name $member.name)
                        $value = $currentFlexAssets.data.attributes.'resource-url'
                        $Split = $value.split("{/}")
                        $members += $Split[7] 
                    }
                    
                    $members
                    $members2 = 1715837278175409, 1715837265510575, 1715837270687920
```

Solved by making an array of the value members $members = @()